# matlab peak value (found the peak but want to know the value)

Tags: matlab

i have plot out the graph and i got some of the code which is here

```
fs = 100; %freq 100hz
N = length(pbcg); %data length, before that do a pbcg=load('pbcg.txt')
duration_in_seconds = N/fs;
duration_in_minutes = duration_in_seconds/60;
BPM_avg = beat_count/duration_in_minutes;

fid = fopen('y1.txt','a'); %txt naming and append

%count the dominant peaks in the signal
for k = 2 : length(pbcg)-1
    if (pbcg(k) > pbcg(k-1) && pbcg(k) > pbcg(k+1) && pbcg(k) > 1)
        beat_count = beat_count + 1;
    end
    fprintf(fid,  'x_axis%i\t ', k); %open writer
    fprintf(fid,  'BPM%i\n ', BPM_avg); %open writer
end
disp(BPM_avg); %display the BPM
fclose(fid); %close writer
```

image of the plotted graph is here(don't have reputation to insert img)...
https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=0525DA685954952E&resid=525DA685954952E%21407&authkey=ALmvTzzQ7Xer2Do

what i want to know is that as you can see that there is 11peak on the highest and how do i get the 'value' in the peak itself? as in i wanna know how to get either the y-axis value or the calculated value.

Comment: You already has all you need in your `if` condition. Inside the `if` you can add `peaks(beat_count)=pbcg(k);`, and you'll get in `peaks` the Y-values of the peaks.

Comment: No reason to be sorry. Your condition is good. I meant you should add another line after the line `beat_count=Beat_count+1`, and before the `end`.

Comment: @Adiel Thank you very much! i know what you mean and i manage to get the peaks.. thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

i do it this way like how @Adiel taught..

```
%determine the bpm

beat_count = 0;
fs = 100; %freq 100hz
N = length(pbcg); %data length, before that do a pbcg=load('pbcg.txt')
duration_in_seconds = N/fs;
duration_in_minutes = duration_in_seconds/60;
BPM_avg = beat_count/duration_in_minutes;

fid = fopen('y1.txt','a'); %txt naming and append

%count the dominant peaks in the signal
for k = 2 : length(pbcg)-1
    if (pbcg(k) > pbcg(k-1) && pbcg(k) > pbcg(k+1) && pbcg(k) > 1)
    beat_count = beat_count + 1;
    peaks(beat_count)=pbcg(k);
end
fprintf(fid,  'x_axis%i\t ', k); %open writer
fprintf(fid,  'BPM%i\n ', BPM_avg); %open writer
end

disp(BPM_avg); %display the BPM
fclose(fid); %close writer
```

and from the matlab command i type 'peaks' and it show me my total number of peaks with the y-axis value. but of coz i do need to clear the "beat_count" and "peaks" as everytime i 'run' the function it will double up the amount of data

Comment: hi @Floris you know this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561419/matlab-plot-graphsegment-by-segment-and-user-input-threshold-value-before-writ