# Matlab load entire file but show and plot segment by segment

Tags: matlab

*Possible to load file and show/plot it segment by segment?* i want to know if it is possible and anyone can guide me along. i have manage to do this [matlab peak value (found the peak but want to know the value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522241/matlab-peak-value-found-the-peak-but-want-to-know-the-value/17538499?noredirect=1#comment25508520_17538499) and now i'm gonna add on to it so i hope you guys don't put my questions on hold/downvoted me. i really need help

example:

Data size: 10000

Intention: To load the entire file, but at 1 time the fig only show 1000 data instead of showing and plotting the entire 10000 data.

Explanation:
When i press some command it will plot the first 1000 data. then i press enter or some command it will plot 1001 - 2000 and so forth..

I have google but don't seems to find any similar questions

need advise..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will be helpful:

```
data = 1:10000;
rows = reshape(data, 1000, numel(data)/1000)';

for ri = 1:size(rows,1)
    figure, plot(rows(ri,:));
    pause;
end
```

It reshapes data vector into matrix 10 x 1000, so that rows contain consecutive 1000 data values. Then just loop over rows and plot them waiting for keypress.

Comment: Hi @Marcin do you know this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561419/matlab-plot-graphsegment-by-segment-and-user-input-threshold-value-before-writ