# Finding the highest peak above threshold only

Tags: matlab

```
if (pbcg(k+M) > pbcg(k-1+M) && pbcg(k+M) > pbcg(k+1+M) && pbcg(k+M) > threshold)

    peaks_y(Counter) = pbcg(k+M);

    peaks_x(Counter) = k + M;

    py = peaks_y(Counter);
    px = peaks_x(Counter);


    plot(px,py,'ro');
    Counter = (Counter + 1)-1;

    fid = fopen('y1.txt','a');
    fprintf(fid, '%d\t%f\n', px, py);
    fclose(fid);
  end
end
```

this code previously doesn't have any issue on finding the peak..
the main factor for it to find the only peak is this
        if (pbcg(k+M) > pbcg(k-1+M) && pbcg(k+M) > pbcg(k+1+M) && pbcg(k+M) > threshold)
but right now it keep show me all the peak that is above the threshold instead of the particular highest peak..

UPDATE: what if the highest peaks have 4nodes that got the same value?

**EDIT:**
If multiple peaks with the same value surface, I will take the value at the middle and plot.

What I mean by that is for example [1,1,1,4,4,4,2,2,2]

I will take the '4' at the 5th position, so the plot will be at the center of the graph u see

Comment: If you have all the peaks it should not be too hard to `find` the one with `max` size.

Comment: i would like to know from the code i posted, how to solve the peaks that got the same value issue? as in if there is 4peaks that is on the same value, the 'IF' code won't be running as it didn't meet the requirement..

as in the max size function only allow peak that is the highest right? or i misread it

Answer (score 3):

It will be much faster and much more readable to use the built-in [max](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function, and then test if the max value is larger than the threshold.

```
[C,I] = max(pbcg);
if C > threshold
    ... 
    %// I is the index of the maximal value, and C is the maximal value.
end
```

Comment: what if for example there are 4 peaks of same value?

Comment: i would like to know from the code i posted, how to solve the peaks that got the same value issue? as in if there is 4peaks that is on the same value, the 'IF' code won't be running as it didn't meet the requirement

Comment: @myfriday13 What do you want to happen if there are multiple peaks with the same value? Currently `I` will contain the first occurance of the maximum.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin if multiple peaks with the same value surface, i will take the value at the middle and plot.. what i mean by that is for example 1,1,1,4,4,4,2,2,2... i will take the '4' at the 5th position.. so the plot will be at the center of the graph u see..

Comment: @myfriday13 That should have been in your question when you asked it. I have now updated it for you and tried to give an answer.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Thanks! it's because every time i step in i have new issues coming up and i forgotten to update.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As alternative solution, you may evaluate the idea of using the built-in function `findpeaks`, which encompasses several methods to ascertain the existance of peaks within a given signal. Within thos methods you may call

```
findPeaks = findpeaks(data,'threshold',threshold_resolution);
```

The only limit I see is that `findpeaks` is only available with the `Signal Processing Toolbox`.

**EDIT**

In case of multiple peaks over the defined threshold, I would just call `max` to figure the highest peak, as follows

```
max(peaks);
```

Comment: what if for example there are 4 peaks of same value?

Comment: @myfriday13: how do you define the highest peak?

Comment: as in you can see that the code i have put up here, if value 'k' is greater than 'k+1' and 'k-1' then the 'k' is greater than the threshold set.. but this won't work anymore.. as at the near peak area, there may be values spiking so end up having lots of peaks.. and if you use median filter, you could even result in peaks that have the same value..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a vector with peaks `pbcg`
Here is how you can get the middle one:

```
highestPeakValue = max(pbcg)
f = find(pbcg == highestPeakValue);
middleHighestPeakLocation = f(ceil(length(f)/2))
```

Note that you can still make it more robust for cases where you have no peaks, and can adjust it to give different behavior when there are two middle peaks (now it will take the second one)